# How To Measure USB Transfer Speed Using CDC Protocol?

Tags: usb, stm32, data-transfer, cdc, cortex-m

I use STM32F7 microcontroller with following specifications.

1) SYS_CLK : 168 MHz.
2) USB_CLK : 168 MHz.
3) USB Speed : High Speed.
4) USB transfer type: CDC device (bulk transfer mode)
5  USB OTG End Point 1 OUT and 1 IN with Global interrupt.

I am testing HS USB on my new STM32F7-DiscoveryBoard and managed to get it work. However, I am very interested to know the data rate.

I can receive data sent from board to my PC and want to know how to measure the data rate.

Please let me know if there is any software / terminals good for knowing the rate of incoming data.

/Jagadeep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a crude solution, but you can make the uC output continously to your PC. Using a terminal program such as PuTTy, setup communcation over a COM port and configure a log file to store all data that has been transmitted. After a few minutes of sending data, you should be able to approximate the transfer speed.